# Are bra-vectors one-forms?

Tags: tensors, quantum-mechanics, dual-spaces, general-relativity

In my intro General Relativity class, we discussed lowering and raising indices with the metric tensor, ie $x_\mu = \eta_{\mu\nu}x^\nu$. This makes some sense to me when I consider the difference between covariance and contravariance, but the distinction between upper and lower indexed tensors is the distinction between vectors and one-forms. What I've read so far matches what we've learned in class, that is that there is a linear map between the space of vectors and the space of one-forms.

However, the class seems to think that the distinction between one-forms and vectors is the same as the distinction between bra-vectors and ket-vectors, from quantum.

This strikes me as odd since there is no linear transformation from a ket vector to its bra vector (because conjugation is not a linear map).

My question is, where am I going wrong? Is the issue that the transformation from a vector space to its dual space is not necessarily linear? Is it the assumption that kets->bras is a transformation from vector to dual vector?

Comment: You will probably want to read about [dual spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) and, in particular, about the [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Bilinear_products_and_dual_spaces) one gets when a bilinear or [sesquilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) product is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big difference between GR and QM is that the vector spaces that represent spacetime in GR are real vector spaces, whereas in QM the vector spaces in which quantum states live are complex vectors spaces. So analogies between one field and the other may require some translation.

There is no natural map between a vector space and its co-vector space of linear functionals a.k.a. one-forms - but we are free to choose a map that makes sense in the context of the physical systems that we are studying. In GR the we often choose to use the metric tensor as a map, and the metric tensor (like all tensors) is linear in both its dimensions. In QM we use the complex scalar product which is not bilinear, but is [sesquilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) instead.